# Connecting to DB with Windows authentication uses Domain\Machine$ user in SQL Server 2016 but it uses Machine\user in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, windows, wcf, authentication, active-directory

I have a bizarre situation here. I desperately need your help, SQL guru or WCF masters!

I have a WCF application (C#) which talks to a SQL Server database with Windows authentication.

On machine A, I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and the user being used when connecting to the database with Windows authentication is `NT Authority\NETWORK SERVICE`. As this user has already been added to my database it connects successfully without issues.

On machine B, I installed SQL Server 2016 Express and the user name being used when connecting to the database with Windows authentication is `Domain\Machine$`.  As `NT Authority\System` has been added my SQL server, it connects successfully but not able to connect to my database.

I am not sure how the user for Windows authentication can be different per SQL Server version. Simple resolution would be altering user mapping of `NT Authority\System` for my database but not so sure if I want that.

Does anyone know what possibly affects the user name being used for Windows authentication? If there is nothing we can do about it, what's the best approach would be for this issue?

Both machines are not in the domain yet (just in `WORKGROUP` as Win 10 OS default image). Both SQL Server services are running as `NT Authority\NETWORK SERVICE`.

Further information:

- Both SQL Servers have been installed with following parameters:

  ```
  /QS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,SDK /INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS"
  /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /SECURITYMODE=SQL
  /SAPWD="ourpassword"
  /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="$SQL_COMPUTER_NAME$\$SQL_USER_NAME$"  
  /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
  ```
- `$SQL_COMPUTER_NAME$\$SQL_USER_NAME$` gets replaced with proper computer and username that logged in.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLZ6o.png) has got detailed error messages obtained from SQL Server login history. First 3 (89,90 and 91) are captured in Machine A.  Second 3 (456-458) are captured from Machine B.

Comment: Are you sure database name is correct?

Comment: Yes. In fact, connection strings used in both machine are the same as well as DB names.

Comment: Either database does not exist (or the name is something else) or login does not have permissions for the database (you need to add the user to database)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Xaqron.  Well... that answer is what I already mentioned above.  But my question is why Windows Authentication uses "Domain\Machine$" in SQL 2016 rather than "NT Authority\NETWORK SERVICE" which was being used in SQL 2008R2.  They are the same application running on different version of SQLs.

Comment: Are you remote to SQL 2016 and local to 2008?

Comment: Nope. Local to both.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` machines gonna act as domain controller in final scenario?

Comment: @Xaqron  Nope...

Comment: Did you see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2511/standardize-sql-server-installations-with-configuration-files) solution?

Comment: @Xaqron That's another way of installing SQL using configuration file (*.ini) instead of using parameters in command line? I do not think that could be an solution? I compared Summary.txt of both SQL installations and not finding anything particularly different.....

Comment: Sorry, that was my best. Your case is special and needs mimic the situation which I don't have the tools. You may expecting too much from Microsoft.

Comment: Are you *certain* that machine B is not yet joined to the domain?  It should be impossible for the domain name to appear as part of a logged-on username, on a machine that isn't in the domain.  (How could it even know what the domain name *is*?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston  They are in WORKGROUP not joined any domain.. That's what I mean - did not know WORKGROUP is also called a domain too?

Comment: You mean the username that SQL reports is `WORKGROUP\Machine$` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes.. Please have a look the link above if you have a moment..

Comment: @HarryJohnston  Also, I ran `gwmi win32_computersystem` in PS... no information about Domain/Domain Controller...

Comment: As a possible workaround, you could try running your application as LOCAL SERVICE instead of NETWORK SERVICE (if WCF will allow you to do so?) as there's very little difference on a non-domain-joined machine and I think it will suppress the behaviour in question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston  Thanks for your help.  I tried to switch from NETWORK SERVICE to LOCAL SERVICE but that does not make much difference. I also ensure to restart all related services along with SQL server service...  Would it be really bad idea to give an access to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for my database?

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure whether that will actually help, but if it does, I don't see why it would be a problem. The SYSTEM account can do whatever it likes, impersonate any other user, examine and/or modify the database files directly, change the SQL permissions itself, and so on, explicitly granting it access to the database doesn't really give it any access it couldn't have gotten another way.

Comment: ... *except*, well, allowing NETWORK SERVICE to access your database (regardless of how you do it) is a bit of a risk, because lots of different services run as NETWORK SERVICE so if any of them are compromised then so is your database.  From a security point of view, using a virtual account would be safer.  That's not really related to your question here, though, it applies just as much to machine A as to machine B.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, It does actually resolve the problem.  It seems that when connecting to DB with Windows authentication, Domain\Machine$ is being used and that follows the user mapping of NT Authority\System.

Comment: It might be worth asking the explicit question, whether giving SYSTEM access to a database (in order to allow NETWORK SERVICE to access it) is a risk.  Perhaps on Database Administrators or Information Security rather than Stack Overflow though.  Don't take my word for it, I'm not familiar enough with SQL to be sure about that side of things.

Comment: @Harry Right... by the way I have further information. I looked up SQL log and found out this:
`The service account is 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'. This is an informational message; no user action is required`.  This might be clue? This log can only be observed from Machine B.   In Machine A, there is no such thing.

Comment: `The service account is 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'. This is an informational message; no user action is required. ` This log message still gets logged in SQL startup whether SQL service runs as `NETWORK SERVICE` or `Local System`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston  Hi Harry, Finally found out  why this log-in failure happened.   `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' is no longer has 'sysadmin' role by default in SQL 2012 and SQL 2016 while it was in 2008 R2.  Although I have not found out why different users gets used for Windows authentication when connecting to DB from my C# application via WCF...

Comment: I can solve this login failure issue either by changing user mapping of `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` or by adding `sysadmin` role back to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` as it has always been in SQL 2008 R2.  But   I decided to add `sysadmin` to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500459(v=sql.110).aspx